# jQuery Calendar with Time Slots selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I want to create an Appointment Booking feature in PHP. I want to have a calender in which user can select date and in return calender shows the time slots to select.

Time slot will be static, it might be dynamic in future.

You can check the example on below link.

https://getbooked.io/

Searched over the internet for such kind of plugins, but could not find. (I need a free plugin).

Comment: This question is [off-topic (#4)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please check this
http://jsfiddle.net/Xx4GS/258/

The idea is on change we are creating the new html element and appending to the datepicker. You need to modify the design according to your need. Call the ajax function in the change event to fetch the time slot from DB. because I can see that the link you gave is also doing the same.

Attaching the code as well:

```
var $datePicker = $("div#datepicker");

var $datePicker = $("div");

$datePicker.datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    inline: true,
    altField: "#datep",
}).change(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){   
        $datePicker
            .find('.ui-datepicker-current-day')
            .parent()
            .after('<tr>\n\
                        <td colspan="8">\n\
                            <div> \n\
                                <button>8:00 am – 9:00 am </button>\n\
                            </div>\n\
                            <button>9:00 am – 10:00 am</button>\n\
                            </div>\n\
                            <button>10:00 am – 11:00 am</button>\n\
                            </div>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                   </tr>');

    });
});
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
$('.date-picker-2').popover({
 html : true, 
 content: function() {
   return $("#example-popover-2-content").html();
 },
 title: function() {
   return $("#example-popover-2-title").html();
 }
});
$(".date-picker-2").datepicker({
 onSelect: function(dateText) { 
        $('#example-popover-2-title').html('<b>Avialable Appiontments</b>');
     var html = '<button  class="btn btn-success">8:00 am – 9:00 am</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">10:00 am – 12:00 pm</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">12:00 pm – 2:00 pm</button>';
     $('#example-popover-2-content').html('Avialable Appiontments On <strong>'+dateText+'</strong><br>'+html);
     $('.date-picker-2').popover('show');
    }
});
```

```css
.popover {
 left: 40% !important;
}
.btn {
 margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=" col-md-4">
      <div  class="date-picker-2" placeholder="Recipient's username" id="ttry" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></div>
      <span class="" id="example-popover-2"></span> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-content" class="hidden"> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-title" class="hidden"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
.popover {
    left: 40% !important;
}
.btn {
    margin: 1%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=" col-md-4">
      <div  class="date-picker-2" placeholder="Recipient's username" id="ttry" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></div>
      <span class="" id="example-popover-2"></span> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-content" class="hidden"> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-title" class="hidden"> </div>
<script>
$('.date-picker-2').popover({
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-title").html();
    }
});
$(".date-picker-2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) { 
        $('#example-popover-2-title').html('<b>Avialable Appiontments</b>');
        var html = '<button  class="btn btn-success">8:00 am – 9:00 am</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">10:00 am – 12:00 pm</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">12:00 pm – 2:00 pm</button>';
        $('#example-popover-2-content').html('Avialable Appiontments On <strong>'+dateText+'</strong><br>'+html);
        $('.date-picker-2').popover('show');
    }
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

> This Is a Static method for showing Available Appointments You Can Use
>   Ajax method in onSelect function of date picker For  Dynamic
>   Appointments

Comment: This is actually a way nicer and looks much better then the accepted answer. It is keeping the structure of the of the datepicker as it is and the pop up with the available hours is a smart decision.

Answer (score 2):

Try FullCalendar: http://fullcalendar.io/

It's a full-featured, free, open-source Javascript calendar plugin. It's very flexible and can do all the things you described. The effort reqiured on your part is to handle the events that you want (e.g. user selecting a time slot) and wire it up to your server-side data. You might want to change the appearance and/or behaviour a little so that it automatically creates slots of the size you need. Like I said, it's incredibly flexible so with a bit of work you should be able to do it.

The documentation provided for doing all this is pretty good. If you get stuck though please post more questions here - I've used it quite a lot and might be able to help.

I'm surprised it didn't turn up in your internet searches already to be honest.

Comment: i want it with the date picker only . .  as given in the ref. link

Comment: don't you want the timeslots as well? It'll give you that too. If you just want a datepicker, use jquery datepicker. But then you'll have to code the timeslots stuff yourself.

Comment: Yes , i want time slots but not with the full calendar, it should popup after user select the date  as given in the example.  check this link https://getbooked.io/

Comment: then a combination of the two - fullcalendar and jQuery datepicker - might be a good way to go. fullcalendar can be restricted to just show one day at a time, and you can work out how to render separate selectable timeslots within that.

Comment: Appreciate your thoughts , but possible like the example i have gave you ?

Comment: by combining those two plugins, yes I think so. You just need to tweak the fullCalendar plugin settings and rendering a bit.

Comment: or if you're honestly returning a static set of slots (as you say you are, but what if one is full already??) then you could just use the datepicker and some custom html of your own

Comment: Slots will be static for sure,if it will be booked then it will be managed from backed manually, we dont need to worry about it. all i want is that user should select the date from the datepicker and datepicker should display those timeslots , if UI is different i dont mind,.

Comment: ok well I would go for jquery Datepicker. You can handle the event of a date being selected and display some custom UI with the timeslots in it. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [jQuery plugin Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) for the `mouseover` and `click` handler to create the row. Check [this sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/Xx4GS/267/) :)

You can either load the month's informations and repeat when the month change, or you can load *on the fly* as I did in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Week Calendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar)

Its full featured opensource plugin. It is built on top of jquery and jquery ui and is inspired by other online weekly calendars such as google calendar. Effort from your side for updating database from server side and some javascript changes in plugin as per your requirement described.
Here is simple demo [Demo](http://themouette.github.io/jquery-week-calendar/weekcalendar.html). [Here is more demos that can help you](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/demos)

Comment: Nope , Cant use this .