# Clarification with timeslot in php/mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995183/jquery-calendar-with-time-slots-selection).

I cannot comment to ask follow up questions because of my low rep.

I understand how to implement the answer in the above mentioned thread but i don't completely understand how to pass the information to my php mysql query. Can someone please help me figure out how to query and insert the data into my mysql database please?

Thank you!

Comment: If an old question doesn't solved your issue, you need to write a complete new one, including  your own code, expected output and what is currently happening. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible approaches here. The first one is to use a standard submit form. You can use a JS code that will store the selected date in some hidden input of the form. When the user hit the submit button the page will reload and the form information will be available for you through $_POST/$_GET (depends on how you have set your form method).

The other approach is to use ajax and send the data with an ajax call to the server and there you can validate it, sanitize it and save it to the database.

If you provide some code and what way you prefer to use for sending the form data I can edit my answer with some code examples.